# Getting error while trying to display a list in view in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting an error

> Object reference not set to an instance and object

when trying to run this ASP.NET Core MVC app.

I'm trying to display the list of all the properties that I'm getting from the controller.

I'm getting the error at this line:

```
@foreach(var s in Model)
```

Can someone please help me in figuring out what am I doing wrong?

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@Using System.Collections
@Using ESBReference
@model IEnumerable<DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo>;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

@foreach(var s in Model)
{
  <li>@s.ACCOUNTNUMBER</li>
  <li>@s.CARDNAME</li>
  <li>@s.CARDNUMBER</li>
  <li>@s.CARDSTATUS</li>
  <li>@s.CARDEXPIRYDATE</li>
}
```

`HomeController`:

```
public class HomeControler : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
       _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            DebitCardServiceClient cli = new DebitCardServiceClient();
            DebitCardList list = new DebitCardList();
            DebitCArdListingRequestDTO reqDTO = new DebitCArdListingRequestDTO();
            reqDTO.cnic = "35***********";

            RequestHeader requestheader = new RequestHeader();
            requestheader.SystemName = "SSK";
            requestheader.RequestID = "" + DateTime.Now.TOFileTime();
            requestheader.TenantID = "***************";
 
            list.RequestHeader =  requestheader;
            list.RequestHeader =  reqDTO;

            var resp = await cli.DebitCardListAsync(list);

            foreach (var card in resp.DebitCardListResponse.DebitCardListResponse1.Cards)
            {
                var s = card.ACCOUNTNUMBER.ToString();
                s += card.CARDNAME.ToString();
                s += card.CARDNUMBER.ToString();
                s += card.CARDSTATUS.ToString();
                s += card.CARDEXPIRYDATE.ToString();
            }

            ViewData["card"] = resp.DebitCardListResponse.DebitCardListResponse1.Cards;
        }
        catch(exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error I'm getting is "object reference not set to an instance and object"

Comment: Your action does not return view with model(e.g. return View(model)). Your frontend need model `IEnummerable<DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo>`,  so where did you set data for this list model? I only see you set data for `DebitCArdListingRequestDTO ` model.

Comment: So what should I return in the view in The action method?

Comment: You need set the data for `IEnummerable<DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo>`. Something like what you did for `DebitCArdListingRequestDTO`. Then use `return View(model)`, model is the instance of the list `DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo`. Why you want to display this list model but do not set/get data for this list model?

Comment: Which line you set the value for `IEnummerable<DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo>` in your action?

Comment: I'm setting the data in the foreach loop

Comment: How can I set/get data for this list model?

Comment: Your foreach loop is just set a string value for `s` and you never use this variable.... Which line you set the data for `IEnummerable<DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo>` and pls check the variable is type of list `DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo` then you can return it (`return View(variable)`).

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Which line you set the data for IEnummerable<DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo>" ?
Actually I'm a beginner in .net core and this is a code written by my senior.
My only task is to display the data in the view

Comment: For example, you can see your action, you have set the value for `DebitCArdListingRequestDTO ` with variable name `reqDTO`, right? Then you can use `return View(reqDTO)` to return the data. And this time your Index view should be like `@model DebitCArdListingRequestDTO` and `@Model.cnic`. Then you can see the `cnic` value displays in the view.

Comment: So for the list how can I do the same?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Index.cshtml`, you use `@model IEnumerable<DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo>;`, so in your controller, you need to pass the `IEnumerable<DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo>` to the view.

I write a simple demo here:

Model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    // For testing convenience, I just hard code here.
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Jack",
                    Country = "USA"
                },
                new Student()
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Nancy",
                    Country = "UK"
                },
                new Student()
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Lily",
                    Country = "Cn"
                }
            };

    // I just return view() here!!!
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model List<Student>

@foreach(var s in Model)
{
  <li>@s.Id</li>
  <li>@s.Name</li>
  <li>@s.Country</li>
}
```

You can see there is an NullReferenceException in `@foreach()`

[image]

But if I write code like this in controller:

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    // For testing convenience, I just hard code here.
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
                {
                    new Student()
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        Name = "Jack",
                        Country = "USA"
                    },
                    new Student()
                    {
                        Id = 2,
                        Name = "Nancy",
                        Country = "UK"
                    },
                    new Student()
                    {
                        Id = 3,
                        Name = "Lily",
                        Country = "Cn"
                    }
                };

    // I return List<Student> from controller to view
    return View(students );
}
```

It will work fine.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I got your point. But in my case what should I return in my "return View();"?

Comment: You use `@model IEnummerable<DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo>;` in View, So I think `DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo` is a model right? But in your controller, I don't find model called `DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo`, So I think you need create `List<DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo> DCLR= new List<DebitCardListingResponseDTOCardInfo>()`, Then put value into `DCLR` from db or anythor else. Finally `return View(DCLR)`.

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: You just need to know if you use `@foreach(var s in Model)`, `Model` must have value, If you iterate over an empty model, It will report NullReferenceException. So you need to pass the same the type of value from controller to view. Because i don't fimilar with your code, So i can't tell you more details, I hope you can get my point.

Comment: How can I know if the model is empty or not?

Comment: If you are new to Asp.net core MVC, I suggest you to read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0) first.